# Drop down menu open by default in php

Tags: php

I have this script for a drop down box which is closed, until the user clicks the down arrow, showing the options. I want it so all the options are displayed from the start, so they don't have to select the down arrow. Does anyone know what i need to change in order to achieve this? I've tried 'open' 'open' on the .toggleClass but that doesn't seem to have changed anything.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
// toggles the refine search field values
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('div.handle').click(function() {
        $(this).next('div.element').animate({
            height: ['toggle', 'swing'],
            opacity: 'toggle' }, 200
        );

        $(this).toggleClass('close', 'open');
        return false;
    });
    <?php foreach ( $_GET as $field => $val ) : ?>
    $('.<?php echo esc_js($field); ?> div.handle').toggleClass('close', 'open');
    $('.<?php echo esc_js($field); ?> div.element').show();
    <?php endforeach; ?>

});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I may be wrong but this is likely to be in your javascript not php, also you may need to say which menu.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there a way i can make it display all the options by default, rather than the user having to click a button to display the options?
The entire code is here: http://pastebin.com/sya8auVG

Comment: This links to a page generating an ordered list of checkboxes - that's not a dropdown box.

Answer (score 1):

Use `multiple` attribute in the select box like this:

```
<select name="xxx" multiple>
    <option value="1">value 1</option>
    <option value="2">value 2</option>
    <option value="3">value 3</option>
</select>
```

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EnzA4/) to see how it appears.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will not do it, you can play with the interactions of form with Javascript.

Use the focus() function on javascript, and the dropdown should automatically be focused.

```
<!-- Your form -->
<form>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>...</option>
</select>
</form>

<!-- Your Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('mySelect').focus();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, could you tell me where i would put this in my javascript? (Iv'e amended my original question)

Comment: @creatix Simply write it at the very bottom of your Javascript (just before the </script>). The line should run automatically when the page finishes loading.

Answer (score 0):

To show all the items without using a dropdown box, you would use the HTML element `<select size="3">` attribute.

Can you show us all the code used to display your select box on the page so we might suggest how to do this? I am guessing you're using a framework of some kind.

```
<select size="3">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

User will see all options appear in a vertical box. They can use `Ctrl` to select multiple options, in which case you'll need to append `[]` to the `select` element's `name` attribute.